# How to specify separators in tolocalestring()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using vue-js and I have this code to show prices

```
{{$store.getters.currency.symbol}} {{Number(product.price).toLocaleString(undefined, { minimumFractionDigits: $store.getters.currency.decimals })}}
```

**Part by part:**

1. `{{$store.getters.currency.symbol}}` = symbol of currency from
   database (e.g `$`)
2. `{{Number(product.price).toLocaleString(undefined, {
   minimumFractionDigits: $store.getters.currency.decimals })}}` = my price (e.g 6,346.00)
3. `minimumFractionDigits: $store.getters.currency.decimals` = `.00` at the end of my number (i just specify how many 0 show after price)

**Now what I need is** to provide separators value for **thousands** and **decimals**, if you see my sample number it separates thousands with comma (,) and decimals with dot (.) .
Same as `minimumFractionDigits` i have values for thousands and decimals in database as well and I wish to use them instead of default ones that you see in my sample number.

**My question is:**

How do I add my own values of separators to my price code?

Comment: Do you really need to keep the format of your user's locale then? Sounds like using a fixed one would be easier.

Comment: @Kaiido i do not get any format from users locals and you see i set locals to `undefined` `toLocaleString(undefined, {...` i just want to change separators based on admins preferences.

Comment: `undefined` will use your user's current locale...

Comment: hmmm, i guess doesn't matter then right? as long as symbol, separators etc. all coming from database

Comment: It does matter, if you use a single format, you can replace your separators very easily since they'll always be the same (e.g decimals = `.` and thousands = `,` in American English). But if you let your user's locale, then they'll get different separators (e.g decimals = `,` and thousands = `.` in German), hence you won't be able to use a simple regex. But doing so, you'll also force everyone to read a particular [numeral system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numeral_systems), and it may also mess up with the position of the separators e.g in Indian English.

Comment: ok, let say i added another column to my database and allow admins to save local of currency like `EN_US` and replaced it with my `undefined` part then how would I change those separators? even with specified local i still will need to set separators based on admin wishes and not locals only.

Comment: Then if you're ok with using a single numeral system, you can simply use a regex replace. For instance with en-US: `num.toLocaleString('en-US').replace(/,/g, thousands_separator).replace(/\./g, decimal_separator)`.

Comment: @Kaiido ok thanks buddy, i'll consider your solution but will wait maybe someone has simpler idea rather than me changing lot's of things.